# Alternative to sys.exit(1) for quitting the test when the url does not change in filling forms

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I've test class with Python and Selenium that has methods to fill forms. After filling one form, the program clicks on "next" to go to the next form. I've noticed that occasionally filling with chrome webdriver; one of the fields is left empty. The program will wait for the time-out of elements in other page before terminating, which can take a long time running the test-suite. So, I used sys.exit(1), when the url does not change to quit the test, so Bamboo server can interpret the exit status. However, with enough tests, sometimes I notice that the url of the UI changes but, the program does not detect it and quits at that point. I was looking for any recommendation to avoid sys.exit(1) and why is program quitting even the url changes in UI.

I needed a way to avoid long test time in failing case, so I used sys.exit(1).
I have tried to use the expected condition of the selenium library selenium.webdriver.support.

```
def goto_next_page(driver, _next_btn_id):
"""
This method handles going to next page, if the url changes after clicking  next, continue otherwise exit with 1.
:param driver : web- driver instance
:param _next_btn_id: element id/ xpath of the next button
:return:
"""
    this_url = driver.current_url
    print("url before change {}".format(this_url))
    # call Webdriver wait in the method.      
    wait_until_clickable(driver, 30, _next_btn_id)
    # Click on the next button to go to the next form
    click_button(driver, _next_btn_id)
    # Changed url
    changed_url = driver.current_url
    print(this_url, changed_url)
    # If the url does not change means the next page is not accessible, quit the script
    if this_url == changed_url:
        print("url did not change")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: return False o raise some custom Exception

Comment: I am going to raise custom exception when I call goto_next_page and expect expception 'e'. With that custom exception, I would want to terminate the test. I can't quite find an alternative to quit that test without using 'sys.exit()'. Thanks for suggestions!